# C++ MinGW-w64 WinAPI: как заполнить ComboBox строками

Tags: c++, winapi, mingw-w64

winapi, пытаюсь заполнить combobox строками но в них попадает только первая буква из списка, пытался вывести в консоль, выводится адрес первой буквы,как мне это исправить? вод собственно код:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <CommCtrl.h>
#include <windowsx.h>

LPCWSTR arr[] = {L"string 1", L"string 2", L"string 3"};
HWND cbox;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp){

switch(msg){
    case WM_CREATE:

            cbox = CreateWindowExW(
            (DWORD)0, 
            L"COMBOBOX", L"...", 
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_VSCROLL,
            10, 10,
            200, 200,
            hwnd,
            (HMENU) 1,
            (HINSTANCE) GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE),
            (LPVOID) nullptr);

            //заполняем поля
            for(LPCWSTR s : arr){
                ComboBox_AddString(cbox, s);
            }

    break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wp, lp);
    }
return 0;
};
```

Comment: Может проблема в том, что вы передаёте юникодную строку, а макрос ожидает обычную?

Comment: Вы вот это сделали, как пишут в [wiki](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/Unicode%20apps/): *To compile Unicode applications, define `_UNICODE` and `UNICODE` in your files when compiling and add `-municode` when linking. GCC will use the appropriate C startups for linking.*

Comment: спасибо zed, ваш комментарий помог решить проблему.